# How do I delete properties of an object stored in localStorage?

Tags: javascript

In localStorage I have a object records.  It has many fields
records[recordId] and I want to be able to delete these entries.  Below is my delete function but it does not work.  All the records remain attached to the records object in local storage.   Not sure what is wrong as I am deleting in what looks like the correct manner.  When I print the records object all the records are still there along with their keys????

```
function deleteLocalRecord(recordId) {
     var records = localStorage.getItem('records');
     var theRecords;
     if (supports_html5_storage()) {

          if (records == null) {
            theRecords = {};
          } else {
            // parse the records
            theRecords = JSON.parse(records);
          }

          theRecords[recordId] = '';  // set the record to empty string.
          delete theRecords[recordId]; // delete the record

          // reset the records object in local storage after change
          localStorage.setItem('records', JSON.stringify(theRecords));

     }
  }

  function supports_html5_storage() 
  {
    try 
    {
        return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
    } 
    catch (e) 
    {
        return false;
    }
   }
```

Comment: You have a global variable `surveys` in there, and a function `supports_html5_storage` too... I doubt anyone can help without knowing what they are.

Comment: `supports_html5_storage()` whats inside that function? If it is returning false, then this function will do nothing.

Comment: Sorry I updated above.  supports local storage is just a check if local storage is supported. The code definitely runs. I notice however I could not set a breakpoint on line with delete.

Comment: @Javascripter mmhmm.  And is it working correctly?  Are you sure the inner code is being hit?

Comment: I ran it through the chrome debugger and it executes but does seem to skip the delete possibly.  It seems to jump to line below.

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log(theRecords);` before and after lines 17/18 to check the behaviour is as expected?

Comment: Khior thanks. Yes, it does delete each record correctly. The problem was I  that after looping and calling I reset with another copy of the records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/K4Zu9/3/)

```
function deleteLocalRecord(recordId) {
    if (localStorageEnabled()) {
        var records = localStorage.getItem('records'),
            theRecords  = JSON.parse(records) || {};

        print(JSON.stringify(theRecords)); // before
        delete theRecords[recordId]; // delete
        print(JSON.stringify(theRecords)); // after

        localStorage.setItem('records', JSON.stringify(theRecords));
        print(localStorage.getItem("records"));
    }
}

var records = {
    "test": "test",
    "stuff": "stuff"
};

localStorage.setItem("records", JSON.stringify(records));
deleteLocalRecord("test");


function print(x) {
    document.body.innerHTML += "<p>" + x + "</p>";
};

function localStorageEnabled() {
    return typeof window["localStorage"] !== "undefined";
};
```

Comment: Yes, this does run correctly, in my case records look more like: "testt" : "{t1:t1val, t2:t2Val}" not sure if that is the difference.

Comment: Ok. It does definitely work. The problem was I was resetting theRecords after looping thru and calling deleteLocalRecord.